# How to replace the image on JOptionPane dialog boxes on the title menu?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Instead of the default java logo, I want a different image on all my dialog boxes.

The image is jpeg and already stored on my desktop. Is there a way to modify the title menu ?

Comment: You don't mean the setIconImage method do you? You're asking how to set the image that comes up when you **don't** explicitly set it?

Comment: Yes, in the top left of the title menu. 
I need some info on setIconImage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't set the title bar icon of a JOptionPaneDialog. To do this you could create your own JDialog and then call the [setIconImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) method.